# How to use "before" in the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-choice, academic-writing

My sentence:

> Before the latter half of the 20th century, connecting electronic components together through wires was very complicated and accompanied with a big chance of failure, that is, until PCBs were invented. The idea of packing  wires and connections into a flat sheet of fiber glass made it easy to connect components together.

I am not quite sure about the usage of the word "before" in this sentence, also, should I use "the second half" instead of "the latter half"?

Also, I am not sure about the correctness of the sentence.

Comment: Printed circuit boards are (and were) not just made of fibreglass (or 'fiberglass'), which is one word.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the correctly pointed out fibreglass error, the whole paragraph looks fine, and the use of 'before' and 'latter half' is alright too.

Comment: How was it that radios and TVs could be economically mass-produced using hand wiring and no printed circuit boards if there was a 'big chance of failure'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I thought the same thing, on reading the passage. For the mere hundreds of connections involve in a radio or TV, it worked pretty well.